# Perfect Forms Of State Verbs

Tags: perfect-constructions

We use perfect to denote our finished,fulfilled actions for example.

I have done my homework

İt implies that the action has been achieved,fulfilled and now my homework is done.

I have been here for 2 hours

When it comes to a state verb we use their perfect forms only with a duration as continuative perfect sentences to denote how long we have been in a state or for the actions that starts in the past and is performed for a duration and still ongoing at the reference time.

I know that a perfect action implies an action which has been achieved but what about state verbs is there a perfect concept for stative verbs?I am confused about without a duration,time span how can a state be achieved?Can we say that the state is achieved if I am currently in that state?

Comment: There are stative verbs and active (action) verbs. Be careful: I have done my homework. tells you two things: As I am speaking, it is finished. It is not ongoing. Also, **it merely signals the past without saying when**. Compare: I finished my homework [an hour ago].

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "achieve" implies a process. If you say that a state has been achieved, you are not invoking the state, but the process of reaching that state. Take "I love her.". That describes a state that I am in now. If that state was achieved, I might express that by "I have begun to love her." or "I came to love her.". 
So, a stative verb describes a state, which is by definition not a process.

Comment: Ah, but have you always loved her? :)